# Get the Current HotSpot Name in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Is there anyway to get the hotspot name in windows phone 8.1 when the hotspot is Active .

Thanks 
Pallam Madhukar.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202863(v=vs.105).aspx) out! That could solve the problem